# Displaying n characters from string and then cutting it after last dot

Tags: php, string

I have problem with this code

```
function retrieveMainPage($conn, $controlNumber)
{
$prep_stmt = "SELECT * FROM blog ORDER BY id DESC";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($prep_stmt);

if ($stmt) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $result = $stmt->get_result();

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $id[] = $row['id'];
        $heading[] = $row['heading'];
        $article[] = $row['article'];
        $image[] = $row['image'];
        $timestamp[] = $row['timestamp'];
    }
} else {
    echo "stmt error";
    die();
}
$daySubtract = substr($timestamp[$controlNumber], 8, 2);
$monthSubtract = substr($timestamp[$controlNumber], 5, 2);
if ($monthSubtract == "01") {
    $monthSubtract = "Jan";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "02") {
    $monthSubtract = "Feb";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "03") {
    $monthSubtract = "Mar";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "04") {
    $monthSubtract = "Apr";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "05") {
    $monthSubtract = "Máj";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "06") {
    $monthSubtract = "Jún";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "07") {
    $monthSubtract = "Júl";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "08") {
    $monthSubtract = "Aug";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "09") {
    $monthSubtract = "Sep";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "10") {
    $monthSubtract = "Okt";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "11") {
    $monthSubtract = "Nov";
} else if ($monthSubtract == "12") {
    $monthSubtract = "Dec";
}
$day = "<p class=\"date\">" . $daySubtract . "</p>";
$month = "<p class=\"month\">" . $monthSubtract . "</p>";
if ($controlNumber < 4) {
    echo "<div class=\"s-12 l-6 post-image\">";
    echo "<a href=\"http://127.0.0.1/WIP/sites/post.php?id$id[$controlNumber]\">";
    echo $image[$controlNumber];
    echo "</a>";
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"s-12 l-5 post-text\">";
    echo "<a href=\"http://127.0.0.1/WIP/sites/post.php?id$id[$controlNumber]\">";
    echo "<h2>" . $heading[$controlNumber] . "</h2>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo untilPeriod($article[$controlNumber]);
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"s-12 l-1 post-date\">";
    echo $day;
    echo $month;
    echo "</div>";
} else {
    echo "<div class=\"s-12 l-11 post-text\">";
    echo "<a href=\"http://127.0.0.1/WIP/sites/post.php?id$id[$controlNumber]\">";
    echo "<h2>" . $heading[$controlNumber] . "</h2>";
    echo "</a>";
    echo untilPeriod($article[$controlNumber]);
    echo "</div>";
    echo "<div class=\"s-12 l-1 post-date\">";
    echo $day;
    echo $month;
    echo "</div>";
}
}

function untilPeriod($text, $length = 440) {
if (strlen($text) > $length) {
    $substr = substr(substr($text, 0, strrpos($text.",", ".")), 0 , $length);
    $pieces = explode(".", $substr);
    array_pop($pieces);
    $text = implode(".", $pieces).".";
}
return $text;
}
```

I'm sending numbers with ajax request from another file containing the $controlNumber (numbers from 0 to 4) because I want to display each time other data from the received array.
Function until period seem to work's but when the $controlNumber is 2 text is not displayed and I'm getting only this "."
**sorry for posting whole code but it is hard to explain my problem if you can't see the code ...

Comment: Can you show any example string?

Comment: can you send the string ?

Comment: *I added example of string

Comment: and Your expected output is ... !!

Comment: First 245 characters from string but characters after last dot should not been seen. So user will not see characters from uncompleted sentence.

Comment: @MartinK. Check The Ans .

Comment: Grab only the first *n* characters from the source string. Then find the last occurrence of `.` (dot) in the string and grab everything from the start until there. Done. Everything you need can be found in the PHP docs, more precisely [the reference on String functions](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.strings.php). [`substr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php) and [`strchr()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strrchr.php) might or might not be of particular interest...

Comment: Two more things: think about what is supposed to happen if the input string length is smaller than *n* and also what is supposed to happen if there is no `.` or the `.` is not actually a full stop but part of an expression or somesuch. Maybe what you actually want to do is cut off so that there are only whole *paragraphs*?

Comment: @MartinK. did my answer stop working?

Comment: @ishegg yes, i had some problems with it when I was loading more positions to array for some reason, I've solved it with @ RïshïKêsh Kümar's code

Comment: What do you mean "more positions to array"? Added more elements to `$row`? I got lost. The accepted answer's code just shows the whole paragraph for me? What do you need?

Comment: @ishegg I'm getting text from the db in $article[] , when the $article is at third position then it outputs only "." , can you help me with it ?

Comment: @MartinK. you probably are setting the variable wrong. I updated my answer to make it a function. Just call it like `untilPeriod($yourVariableHere)`. Make sure to set the parameter correctly.

Comment: @ishegg I'll check it out, anyway here's screenshot of problem http://prntscr.com/ghtnlv

Comment: Update your question to show the actual code you're using, to see what the problem is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153791/discussion-between-martin-k-and-ishegg).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to cut the string, then explode by periods, remove the last element, join all the pieces and place the last dot. Also, check if your string is larger than what you want to cut it to. If it's not, leave it as is. Like this:

```
<?php
$length = 250;
$row["article"] = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tempor ut quam in dapibus. Morbi in tortor fermentum, ornare ex quis, pulvinar ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris sollicitudin risus et pulvinar eleifend. Aenean id nisl risus. Aenean eu efficitur enim. Suspendisse condimentum ornare ullamcorper. Nulla aliquet nisl non fermentum convallis. Quisque bibendum nunc sit amet augue dictum, et placerat urna hendrerit. Maecenas consequat libero convallis tincidunt auctor. Mauris ultrices risus non nulla viverra, vitae convallis mauris hendrerit. Fusce eget suscipit ligula. Proin quis pharetra nulla, non elementum dui. Sed commodo ut dui vel iaculis. Suspendisse mattis auctor arcu non dignissim. Cras ut accumsan nunc.

Phasellus in mollis nisi. Etiam tellus dui, ultrices sed nisl vel, dapibus egestas erat. Fusce turpis augue, condimentum eu cursus eu, imperdiet sollicitudin augue. Nulla facilisi. Mauris vel fermentum nunc, porta laoreet dolor. Morbi malesuada congue arcu id dictum. Maecenas maximus semper lectus in rutrum. Etiam sit amet sapien finibus, pellentesque augue eget, scelerisque felis. Sed posuere semper tristique. Nullam cursus eget felis vel ultricies. Morbi molestie ullamcorper varius. Cras ipsum velit, vehicula eu purus vitae, molestie dapibus odio. Cras sit amet vulputate massa, et ullamcorper justo.



Donec in massa ut dui varius faucibus. Maecenas lacinia suscipit nisl, at condimentum nunc. Nulla dignissim interdum arcu sed egestas. Integer finibus mauris nec orci pellentesque porttitor. Phasellus bibendum, quam nec cursus lobortis, diam sapien sodales est, laoreet fringilla erat ipsum vitae arcu. Pellentesque lobortis ante vitae vehicula vehicula. In laoreet, ante ut consectetur efficitur, dolor sem imperdiet urna, eget consectetur orci felis at odio. In iaculis orci et massa dictum, ac rhoncus velit vehicula. Donec felis arcu, placerat finibus blandit dapibus, vulputate id eros. Ut lorem mi, efficitur id lorem et, tincidunt pellentesque mi. Integer lacinia a quam sit amet efficitur. Blah Blah. Test";
function untilPeriod($text, $length = 100) {
    if (strlen($text) > $length) {
        $substr = substr(substr($text, 0, strrpos($text.",", ".")), 0 , $length);
        $pieces = explode(".", $substr);
        array_pop($pieces);
        $text = implode(".", $pieces).".";
    }
    return $text;
}
echo untilPeriod($row["article"]);
```

**Output**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tempor ut quam in dapibus. Morbi in tortor fermentum, ornare ex quis, pulvinar ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos.

[Demo](https://eval.in/856270)

Comment: its 100 characters ??

Comment: It's `n`. Just change the 250 to whatever.

Answer (score 1):

> **Working Demo: ( 100 Characters View )** https://eval.in/856462

```
<?php 

   // Here., Mystr Var is Your $row["article"]

$Mystr ="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tempor ut quam in dapibus. Morbi in tortor fermentum, ornare ex quis, pulvinar ex. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Mauris sollicitudin risus et pulvinar eleifend. Aenean id nisl risus. Aenean eu efficitur enim. Suspendisse condimentum ornare ullamcorper. Nulla aliquet nisl non fermentum convallis. Quisque bibendum nunc sit amet augue dictum, et placerat urna hendrerit. Maecenas consequat libero convallis tincidunt auctor. Mauris ultrices risus non nulla viverra, vitae convallis mauris hendrerit. Fusce eget suscipit ligula. Proin quis pharetra nulla, non elementum dui. Sed commodo ut dui vel iaculis. Suspendisse mattis auctor arcu non dignissim. Cras ut accumsan nunc.

Phasellus in mollis nisi. Etiam tellus dui, ultrices sed nisl vel, dapibus egestas erat. Fusce turpis augue, condimentum eu cursus eu, imperdiet sollicitudin augue. Nulla facilisi. Mauris vel fermentum nunc, porta laoreet dolor. Morbi malesuada congue arcu id dictum. Maecenas maximus semper lectus in rutrum. Etiam sit amet sapien finibus, pellentesque augue eget, scelerisque felis. Sed posuere semper tristique. Nullam cursus eget felis vel ultricies. Morbi molestie ullamcorper varius. Cras ipsum velit, vehicula eu purus vitae, molestie dapibus odio. Cras sit amet vulputate massa, et ullamcorper justo.



Donec in massa ut dui varius faucibus. Maecenas lacinia suscipit nisl, at condimentum nunc. Nulla dignissim interdum arcu sed egestas. Integer finibus mauris nec orci pellentesque porttitor. Phasellus bibendum, quam nec cursus lobortis, diam sapien sodales est, laoreet fringilla erat ipsum vitae arcu. Pellentesque lobortis ante vitae vehicula vehicula. In laoreet, ante ut consectetur efficitur, dolor sem imperdiet urna, eget consectetur orci felis at odio. In iaculis orci et massa dictum, ac rhoncus velit vehicula. Donec felis arcu, placerat finibus blandit dapibus, vulputate id eros. Ut lorem mi, efficitur id lorem et, tincidunt pellentesque mi. Integer lacinia a quam sit amet efficitur. Blah Blah. Test";

  //$pos = strrpos($Mystr, '.');

   $withOutDot[] = substr($Mystr, 0,100). '.';

   $MyString = implode(" ",$withOutDot);

   echo $MyString;

?>
```

**Output:**

> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Duis tempor ut quam in dapibus. Morbi in to.

Comment: This answer is almost correct but my problem is that I want to display  for example first 100 characters from string

Comment: only for first 100 character ??

Comment: Yes, only first 100 characters for example

Comment: @MartinK. okzz wait .. i will try .

Comment: `$withOutDot = substr($Mystr,0,100). '.';`  Just use This Code and Comment the Fisrt One

Comment: @MartinK. .. Check The Ans .. : )

Comment: @MartinK. You Said the 100 Characters to Show,,,

Comment: @MartinK. .. Check the ans right if you get the ans . Thank you

Comment: I managed to get them both working but i cant flag both as correct :), thank you for help

Comment: Thnx Martin ... :) And don't forget .the parameters of substr.... `withOutDot = substr($Mystr,your-string-started-value,limit-of-characters)`

Comment: Now .. , i am in phone I updated my ans with first 100 characters also.. as soon as .. okzz

Comment: Well I'm having problem with both answers now ... this is string is in $article[] variable which is array , when the array reach third position it displays only "."

Comment: Martin then ... Convert the array into the string... Then that string variable you can pass it directly ...

Comment: As I said right now I am using cellphone ... So it's difficult to do for me... But I will guide you... For reference of implode ... Example here https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_implode.asp

Comment: Okay, I'll post comment here later if I'll be not able to figure it out :)

Comment: Okzz ... Sure :)

Comment: @MartinK. ...I Updated My Ans ... its too easy !!